# Can't switch to A2DP sink

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 18.10, a2dp

I'm using a Sony headset on Ubuntu 18.10. When I configure the device and connect it for first time it works great. The default profile is A2DP. However, every time I turn the device off and then turn it on again it switches to HSP/HFP profile and it cannot be changed to A2DP. Only way to do is to remove the device from the Bluetooth manager and configure it again. It is tiresome to do this every time I want to use it.
Any way to fix this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Sounds like a bug that needs fixed, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and file the bug against pulseaudio

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same problem, so I hacked up a small script as a workaround: https://github.com/valderman/bt-reload-headphones

When a Bluetooth device which supports the audio sink profile is connected, the script attempts to switch it over to audio sink. If this fails, it disconnects the device and then reconnects it. This "fixes" the issue for me (Sony WH-1000XM2), but YMMV.